# Render to bitmap using arsd nanovega

Tags: image, d

I want to render some graphics, texts and shapes to a bitmap using a canvas-like API like nanovega in D on my server.

I know how to create an arsd window with OpenGL context and render to it, (as per [documentation](https://arsd-official.dpldocs.info/arsd.nanovega.html)) but is it also possible rendering to a headless context or even directly to draw to some memory buffer? (Because I don't think my server has OpenGL available and would probably need to use some software renderer)

Mainly I wanted to use gradients, texts, shapes, rounded corners, images and masks and render all of that to an image. I know that nanovega implements all of the rendering parts of that, so I would like to keep using it.

Comment: that's on the todo list..... so not implemented natively. But it should be possible to render it using a software opengl implementation and then screenshot that window back to a file.. Are you doing it to like serve an image online or something?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe yes I want to use it to generate an image on the server and then upload it to a HTTP API for display elsewhere, and I wanted to use some native D library for this. For now I will try Cairo using gtkd then as long as it's not implemented.

Comment: Would something like cairo, skia or OpenCV do? I am sure there are bindings to these three libraries...

Comment: for now I'm using cairo, but I will keep this open until it's supported in nanovega and answer it then or if someone posts some clever workaround using it